# Web Server / App Server multiple AZ's for traffic AWS and General Questions

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, amazon-rds

Looking to see if someone can help me in regards to setting up a website VIA AWS and how traffic can be efficiently handled.

(EC2) 16 Cluster Web/App Server - (Wanting to split between US and Europe availability zone (AZ) on AWS) US - 8 clusters EU - 8 clusters

(RDS) - 4 DB Servers - 1 Active, 1 Passive, 2 Slaves - Setup for multi-AZ

(S3) - 1TB. Storage - US AZ

(Cloudfront) - 8TB.

(Route 53) - DNS

The reasoning why I want a web server and app server in EU is because majority of user base is in EU(50%), but traffic still comes from the US (30%) and the company is based in the US as well.

The question I also pose how will direction and load balancing work? How will it know to direct a EU to the EU web server and US user to the US web server? While elastically balancing the load. Making the two AZ work efficiently together managing I/O and traffic capacity?

Is there anything I can do better? Also this must all strictly AWS services.

Thanks!

Comment: You are using incorrect terminology, which is probably why your searches haven't already turned up answers to your question. "Wanting to split between US and Europe availability zone" that's actually splitting between AWS **Regions**, not just AZs. Also, there is no such thing as "US AZ", there are currently 3 US Regions, each with multiple AZs internal to that Region. Splitting traffic across AZs in the same region is trivial, but once you start splitting between Regions it becomes very complicated (and which AZs you are using in each Region become fairly irrelevant).

Comment: Also, depending on what type of application this is, a CDN like CloudFront might be sufficient to serve your application in multiple regions without having to distribute the actual servers across multiple regions. Information like the type of application, how much can be cached by the CDN, and the amount of database reads vs. writes, is necessary to determine if splitting your application servers across regions actually makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

As Mark B commented, your terminology is incorrect. Listen to his comments and get the terminology right. Once you do that, Google searches will start giving you answers.

I'll address a few points here:

> The question I also pose how will direction and load balancing work? How will it know to direct a EU to the EU web server and US user to the US web server? While elastically balancing the load. Making the two AZ work efficiently together managing I/O and traffic capacity?

You're going to separate these into two separate things:

1. Directing EU customers to EU region, and directing US customers to the US region.

You're going to do this to reduce latency to each of these users. To do this, you're going to use Route 53's "latency based routing".

2. Load balance each region independently of one another.

For this, you're going to use Elastic Load Balancers and EC2 instances in multiple availability zones.

You will not "load balance" between US and EU. The US region will be load balanced and the EU region will be load balanced.

> (RDS) - 4 DB Servers - 1 Active, 1 Passive, 2 Slaves - Setup for multi-AZ

You're going to setup your main DB server in either US or EU. This will be Multi-AZ and you'll need to use this server to perform **all writes**, even from the other region.

You can then setup 1 read-replica in each of your regions to help reduce read time.

> (S3) - 1TB. Storage - US AZ

Depending on how the storage will be used, you could use 2 buckets, one in each region. Objects could be replicated between buckets.